# Undefined method `respond_to' for Api::V1::Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I already went through the topics here but the solutions mentioned didn't work out for me.

I want to create an API for my rails application and followed the tutorial from Railscast for API versioning. I am using Rails 5.

This is my `routes.rb` file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
    namespace :v1 do
        resources :orders
    end
  end

end
```

And this the new`orders_controller.rb` under `controllers/api/v1`:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class OrdersController < ApplicationController

        respond_to :json

        def index
            respond_with Order.all
        end

    end
  end
end
```

When visiting `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/orders` I always get the following exception:

```
undefined method `respond_to' for Api::V1::OrdersController:Class Did you mean? respond_to?
```

I have already added `responder` to my gemfile but that didn't work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your orders controller, you made a spelling mistake. Change

```
repsond_with Order.all
```

to

```
respond_with Order.all
```

Also, you made a spelling mistake in your routes file too. Change:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'josn' } do
```

to

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
```

Comment: Oh, thanks ;) But still getting the same error unfortunately

Comment: Did you by any chance forget to run `rails g responders:install`

Comment: Also, you mentioned that installing the `responder` gem didn't work out. The gem name is plural though, so if you add `gem responders` to your gemfile and run `bundle install`, you should be good

Comment: A lot of silly mistakes here, sorry for wasting your time ... But thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes, and that was also the reason why `rails g resonder:install`failed all the time...

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it. Would you mind accepting the answer if you feel that I helped you solve your problem? Also, those little spelling mistakes can be really hard to find without an extra pair of eyes haha

Comment: Sure, I just needed to wait 2 minutes because of any reason before I could accept ;)